# Cannot display comment in page

Tags: comment-form, comments

I added some custom fields in comment, so i have a couple of more fields. 

from that form I can comment but am unable to display that comment. The comments are set to moderation so admin have to approve the comments. 
The value of the new fields are saved on database.

 what I've done so far,
displayed the comment form via `comment_form()`

But `wp_list_comments( array( 'style' => 'ol' ) );` is not retriving any comments.

 Discussion page looks like this
[image]

Also the comments in  backend looks like this
[image]
Well I think in general `wp_list_comments( array( 'style' => 'ol' ) );` should get the comments. But it is not displaying anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you are using the function wp_list_comments but you should use it in the theme comments.php template file and call it using [comments_template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/) function.

If you want to display comments anywhere else then you can use function [get_comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

Comment: That worked thanks.. like you said i used `comments_template` like this `if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
comments_template();`